# Slow ping times when adding new device to home network

Tags: networking, internet-connection, ping

I have problem with internet connection and I'd like to note, that I don't have big knowledge if this matter. Usually in my home, there are 2 devices using internet (one is wi-fi, another is on cable), but from time to time, there's 3rd device present (wi-fi). When this device switches PC on, suddenly 2 other devices drop ping.

While normally it's 24ms, with 3rd device connected, both devices start having ping in range of 24 - 600ms, although we don't drop packets. It's not router problem, because it's happening with 2 different routers. If this device isn't using internet, but PC is on, the ping stabilizes to around 24 - 80ms. What can I do to solve this problem? Can I maybe somehow limit the 3rd device's connection, so the other devices don't have this problem?

Comment: Is the third device running any "intensive" applications. I'm thinking along the lines of a Bit Torrent client or a cloud storage client that is syncing local files onto the internet as soon it gets online

Comment: Which type if internet connection are you using? ADSL, Cable, 3G, ...? Could you also clarify what the devices are? Like PC, notebook, smartphone.

Comment: You may also have an IP conflict if the third PC is set to a manual IP. More likely what Windos said, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the always the same device being connected? If so I agree with Windos there could be an application installed on the third device hogging the network. Try installing a traffic monitoring app such as [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) to monitor the traffic on the third device. This would give you an indication of what is causing the high ping rates.

To investigate the issue even deeper you can setup ICS or Internet Sharing (depending if you are running Win/Mac) on one of your devices (Device A) and connect Device A to the router via ethernet. Now you can connect all devices on the network via Device A and install [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) on Device A to monitor all the traffic flowing through your network.